# Inverted LIKE statement in JPQL using parameter

Tags: java, sql, parameters, jpql, sql-like

this is what I'm trying to achive:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Info.search", query = "SELECT info FROM INFO info 
WHERE info.content LIKE ?1 OR info.content LIKE ?2 OR ?1 LIKE info.content OR ?2 LIKE info.content")
```

The problem is that JPQL throws an exception: `You have attempted to set a value of type class java.lang.String for parameter 1 with expected type of class java.lang.Boolean from query string`

This tells me that the JPQL doesn't let me to give parameters before an operator in the `where` statement like: `where ?1 like someColumn`

How can I work around this and get the info I need ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can only use parameters for values not the name of a column, the only way around it would be string parsing yourself. However your query looks a bit strange why would `info.content like ?1` be different then `?1 like info.content` the latter looks also weird how would you compare a value with the column content (instead of the other way around?

Comment: Hm, try parentheses around all likes: `(info.content LIKE ?1)`.

Comment: @M.Deinum A better way to explain, try to transform this sql query into what I said in the post for jpql: `SELECT * FROM info WHERE content LIKE "%example%" OR "example" LIKE CONCAT("%",content,"%")`